C# CS1061 Error with '.Request' (Trying to update users in an Azure AD B2C through external app)
I have been struggling with a CS1061 error for '.Request()' and cannot seem to figure it out, if anyone can think of a solution or a work around it would be greatly appreciated!
The program is running .NET 8 and using Microsoft.graph, microsoft.graph.core and Azure.Identity packages, all up to date.
 static void UpdateUser()
 {
     var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

     var tenantId = "...";


     var clientId = "...";
     var clientSecret = "...";

     ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
     var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

     Console.WriteLine("Updating a user...");

     Console.Write("Enter the Object ID of the user to update: ");
     string objectId = Console.ReadLine();

     try
     {

         var user = graphClient.Users[objectId].GetAsync().Result;

         // Display current user attributes
         Console.WriteLine($"Current attributes of the user with Object ID {objectId}:");
         Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Email Address: {user.Identities[0].IssuerAssignedId}"); 
         Console.WriteLine($"Business Phone Number: {user.BusinessPhones?[0]}"); 

         // Prompt the user to update attributes
         Console.WriteLine("Enter new values for the user's attributes (press Enter to keep current value):");

         Console.Write("New Display Name: ");
         string newDisplayName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("New Given Name: ");
         string newGivenName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("New Surname: ");
         string newSurname = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("New Email Address: ");
         string newEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("New Business Phone Number: ");
         string newBusinessPhone = Console.ReadLine();

         // Update user attributes
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newDisplayName))
             user.DisplayName = newDisplayName;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGivenName))
             user.GivenName = newGivenName;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newSurname))
             user.Surname = newSurname;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEmailAddress))
             user.Identities[0].IssuerAssignedId = newEmailAddress;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newBusinessPhone))
         {
             if (user.BusinessPhones == null)
                 user.BusinessPhones = new List<string>();

             user.BusinessPhones.Clear(); 
             user.BusinessPhones.Add(newBusinessPhone); 
         }

         // Update the user in Azure AD B2C
         graphClient.Users[objectId].Request().UpdateAsync(user).Wait();
         Console.WriteLine("User updated successfully");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error updating user: {ex.Message}");
     }
 }

Hopefully this information is suffice, if there is any other info I can provide that may help feel free to ask (I am fairly new to coding so good chance I have missed something!).
Thanks in advance.
I have tried rebuild and cleaning the program, I also asked chatGPT if it has any ideas why this may not work, but it could not provide a fix. All packages have been updated.

In latest versions of Microsoft Graph module, Request() is removed and no longer needed. To resolve the error, you need to remove Request() from code. Refer this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api

Initially, I registered one application and granted User.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type as below:

To update the users in Azure AD B2C, you can make use of below modified code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateUser().Wait();
    }

    static async Task UpdateUser()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var clientId = "appId";
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        Console.WriteLine("Updating a user...");

        Console.Write("Enter the Object ID of the user to update: ");
        string objectId = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            var user = await graphClient.Users[objectId].GetAsync();

            // Display current user attributes
            Console.WriteLine($"Current attributes of the user with Object ID {objectId}:");
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Email Address: {user.Mail}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Business Phone Number: {user.BusinessPhones?[0]}");

            // Prompt the user to update attributes
            Console.WriteLine("Enter new values for the user's attributes (press Enter to keep current value):");

            Console.Write("New Display Name: ");
            string newDisplayName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("New Given Name: ");
            string newGivenName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("New Surname: ");
            string newSurname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("New Email Address: ");
            string newEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("New Business Phone Number: ");
            string newBusinessPhone = Console.ReadLine();

            // Update user attributes
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newDisplayName))
                user.DisplayName = newDisplayName;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGivenName))
                user.GivenName = newGivenName;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newSurname))
                user.Surname = newSurname;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEmailAddress))
                user.Mail = newEmailAddress;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newBusinessPhone))
            {
                if (user.BusinessPhones == null)
                    user.BusinessPhones = new List<string>();

                user.BusinessPhones.Clear();
                user.BusinessPhones.Add(newBusinessPhone);
            }

            // Update the user in Azure AD B2C
            await graphClient.Users[objectId].PatchAsync(user);
            Console.WriteLine("User updated successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error updating user: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
Upgrade-to-v5.0 · microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet changes · GitHub

Thankyou so much for the detailed and speedy answer, it is now working perfectly, appreciate it!
